# Why does my javascript code not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create new.html and new.js files .

new.html codes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span id="first">6</span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="seconde">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><span id="third">X</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And new.js codes:

```
$(document).keyup(function () {
    $(document).change(function () {
        var first= document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;
        var seconde= document.getElementById('seconde').value;
        var third= parseInt(first) * parseInt(seconde);
        document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = third;
    });
});
```

When I select a number, X not changed.

For example I want replace number 30 with X when I select 5 in select section . But X not change . How can I do that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to add the change handler [onDocumentReady](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) because in the select drop-down you don't type anything , has no sense to add the handler on keyup event

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).change(function () {
        var first= document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;
        var seconde= document.getElementById('seconde').value;
        var third= parseInt(first) * parseInt(seconde);
        document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = third;
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span id="first">6</span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="seconde">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><span id="third">X</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But... Binding to a global change handler still does not seem a good idea, as when you add more inputs etc. on a page with a change event they will fire this event.

Answer (score 1):

your event bindings seem to be wrong... You need to bind to the change event on the select.

I think this is what you want:

```js
    $('#seconde').change(function () {
        var first= document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;
        var seconde= document.getElementById('seconde').value;
        var third= parseInt(first) * parseInt(seconde);
        document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = third;
    });
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span id="first">6</span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="seconde">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><span id="third">X</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#seconde').on('change',function () {
        var first= document.getElementById('first').innerHTML;
        var seconde= document.getElementById('seconde').value;
        var third= parseInt(first) * parseInt(seconde);
        document.getElementById('third').innerHTML = third;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="new.js"></script> <title>Untitled Document</title> <style> table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; } td { border: 1px solid black; } </style> </head> <body> <table> <tr> <td><span id="first">6</span></td> <td> <select id="seconde"> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> </select> </td> <td><span id="third">X</span></td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>
```